# Jar file won't run after Build artifact - JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, fxml

I have a JavaFx Project which contain FXML files with their controllers and the main class

[Project Scource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxBg4.jpg)

the program works perfectly on the IDE " IntelliJ "
but when i try to make an artifact and build it , the jar file just won't run " JRE installed of course "

I tried many ways to build the artifact so is there a specific way to build jar files that contain FXML files ?

[Building the artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ICVV.jpg)

StackTrace Exception

```
 Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:20)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

The Main Class contain this " FXML Loader "

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Sample/MainLayout.fxml"));

            primaryStage.setTitle("Estimated Download Time");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 764, 600));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Logo.png")));
            primaryStage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

Comment: "The jar file just won't run". What actually happens? Do you get exceptions? If not, have you tried running the jar file from the command line to see if it generates a stack trace that way?

Comment: i'm actually getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Exception in Application start method
but the program run Perfectly on the IDE !

Comment: So post the complete stack trace in the question. Probably the path to the FXML file is not correct, or the FXML file is not being deployed to the jar file.

Comment: i updated the question and i add the StackTrace Exception , Thank you !

Comment: Can't you post it as text? I can't possibly read that.

Comment: Done , many thanks

Comment: OK, so that definitely indicates that the path to the FXML file cannot be found. Can you post the code you are using to load the FXML? The other thing you probably want to do is to look at the content of the jar file (from the command line, you can do `jar tf my_jar_file.jar`, and it will list the contents): that will show you if the FXML file is in there.

Comment: The FXML Files do exist in the Jar file , i posted my main class code , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem by just deleting the Package name from the FXML loader

instead of

```
root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Sample/MainLayout.fxml"));
```

I deleted the package name "Sample" so it became this

```
 root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));
```